# nuSOAP static class method naming

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, soap-client

I'm trying to get the `nuSOAP` library to expose a SOAP method that isn't named the same. Right now I am doing:

```
$server->register('receiveResponseXML');

function receiveResponseXML () ...
```

This works and I'm using it currently, but it's hard to organize and if I have a method name conflict I don't have a way to resolve it. How would I declare a `static` method but expose it named as above? Something like this:

```
$server->register('receiveResponseXML', array('MyClass', 'theStaticMethod'));

class MyClass {
     public static function theStaticMethod() ...
```

Also if anyone knows a legit nuSOAP reference I would much appreciate. Currently I have to read source.

Comment: nuSoap is looking rather long in the tooth. I would think about using teh inbuilt SOAP client that PHP5 has

Comment: Yeah @Bingy I was going to go that way, but nusoap made it very easy to generate a wsdl. I may continue to use it for the generation, and just use the php5 implementation for the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the register function:

> @param string $name *the name of the PHP function, class.method or class..method*

so it would be:

```
$server->register('myClass.receiveResponseXML' ... );
```